# Type Expected error with Linq expression

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to write a linq query in VB.net that groups a list of custom objects by a string and sums the amounts. I have been working from the 101 Linq examples but have run into the Type Expected error when I try and process the collection.

Here is my Linq query:

```
Dim summedAndGrouped = From s As GLLine In _ListOfGLLines
                       Group s By s.SEDOL Into grouped = Group
                       Select SEDOL, TotalIncome = grouped.Sum(Function(s) s.Income)
```

Adapted from the Linq 101 samples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737904#sumgroup

I'd very much appreciate any advice. Below is my test project which I'm using to try and figure this one out:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

<TestClass()>
Public Class UnitTest1

    Private _ListOfGLLines As New List(Of GLLine)

    <TestInitialize()>
        Public Sub Setup()
        SetupGLLinesCollection()
    End Sub

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub TestMethod1()
        Dim summedAndGrouped = From s As GLLine In _ListOfGLLines
                               Group s By s.SEDOL Into grouped = Group
                               Select SEDOL, TotalIncome = grouped.Sum(Function(s)    s.Income)

        Assert.AreEqual(summedAndGrouped.Count, 3)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetupGLLinesCollection()
        _ListOfGLLines.Add(New GLLine("Bob1", 20, 10, 4, 6))
        _ListOfGLLines.Add(New GLLine("Bob1", 20, 10, 4, 6))
        _ListOfGLLines.Add(New GLLine("Bob2", 20, 10, 4, 6))
        _ListOfGLLines.Add(New GLLine("Bob2", 20, 10, 4, 6))
        _ListOfGLLines.Add(New GLLine("Bob3", 20, 10, 4, 6))
        _ListOfGLLines.Add(New GLLine("Bob3", 20, 10, 4, 6))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class GLLine
    Public Property SEDOL As String
    Public Property Income As Decimal
    Public Property PID As Decimal
    Public Property Interest As Decimal
    Public Property Dividend As Decimal

    Public Sub New(SEDOL, Income, PID, Interest, Dividend)
        _SEDOL = SEDOL
        _Income = Income
        _PID = PID
        _Interest = Interest
        _Dividend = Dividend
    End Sub
End Class
```

Edit: It appears that this query evaluates fine, my confusion was caused because when I hover over the summedAndGrouped variable it gives me the Type Expected error, which I assume is due to the compiler needing to infer the type of the iterator before it can evaluate the query. I'd still appreciate confirmation of why this occurs and how to avoid it.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is in this code? I can compile and successfully run the test.

Comment: My apologies, I did not realise but this does in fact work fine, the error occurs when I hover over the in memory query summedAndGrouped on the Assert.AreEqual line. I assume that this is because the compiler needs to infer the type before it can evaluate the query. Thanks for taking the time to look at this, I'll edit my question accordingly.